# How to suppress server errors in Craft?

Tags: plugins, error-handling, plugin-imager

On certain pages of my site, I download and display resized (using the [Imager](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/imager) plugin) images from remote site.

Now, sometimes that remote site returns error and in such case Imager is throwing exceptions, blocking the whole page from being viewed.

Now, is there a way to suppress server errors when possible, e.g. write them to log file and don't stop page processing?

[devMode](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/imager) is set to `false`.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Telling image can't be resized (related to the fact that the remote server does not return 404 code but merely showing 'not found' page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of errors that are being thrown.  If they are Twig/template errors, then you can can set the [suppressTemplateErrors](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#suppressTemplateErrors) config setting to `true` and they will simply get logged and the page request will continue as usual.

If they are non-Twig exceptions, then you'd have to do something more fancy like make a plugin that's essentially a facade for the Imager plugin and wraps all of it's calls in a `try/catch` block that just swallows any exceptions.

Or make a pull request that added support for it to the plugin itself.

Comment: Good idea about creating a wrapper. I'll try that, thanks @Brad Bell

Comment: Ended up modifying Imager and submitting pull request